# android textView style with vertical line on the left

Tags: android, styles, textview

Is there any way i can give a style to my TextView [without using other widgets] like the style for the NOTE in the screenshot below? [a vertical line to the left]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something similar to the following?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, this works but i dont really want to use this because the textview's visibility changes a lot during runtime so it will be cumbersome, so i dont wanna use any widgets

Answer (score 0):

Try using any image you want on left of textview by using android:drawableLeft for textview

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon" />
```

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for...but can the height  of the drawable be adjusted dynamically according to the text in the textview?

Comment: creating a 9-patch image for the drawable would be my suggestion. then, the height would adjust by itself